# Django create user profile

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I created a user profile model for my system. I created all models and it works perfectly. I have a form, and the form works too. But when I look user create form from **admin** page, it doesn't look the same.

There are some missing parts like rank, `comp_name`. How can I fix it?

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ranks = (
        ('xxx', 'xxx'),
          ...
    
    )
    comp_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="Choose")
    user_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4(), editable=False, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=ranks)
```

**forms.py**

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    comp_name = forms.CharField(label='What is your company name?')
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=254)
    rank = forms.ChoiceField(label='What is your rank?', choices=UserProfile.ranks)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=250)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=250)
    comp_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CompanyProfile.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'comp_name',  'password1', 'password2', 'rank'
```

**admin**
[admin panel "Change User" screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NudnM.png)

Comment: To create a custom user model, you need to inherit from `AbstractUser` and set your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting. There are instructions in the django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Answer (score 0):

In forms.py

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    comp_name = forms.CharField(label='What is your company name?')
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=254)
    rank = forms.ChoiceField(label='What is your rank?', choices=UserProfile.ranks)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=250)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=250)
    comp_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CompanyProfile.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = User --> change to UserProfile
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'comp_name',  'password1', 'password2', 'rank'
```

Comment: Yes. I migrate it